# Python - Dynamics CRM Web API - SuppressDuplicateDetection Not working

Tags: python, api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am running into an issue with the ability to [Suppress Duplicate Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/manage-duplicate-detection-create-update) in the Dynamics CRM API. I am qualifying leads and the Duplicate Detection is getting triggered on some of the leads. I have some logic to decide if we want to suppress the so on certain leads I want to bypass that detection.

What is happening is it is not working when in the request headers I set the `MSCRM.SuppressDuplicateDetection: true` and it will still not qualify the lead.

Here is my full code:

```
    api_surpress_dup_detection_headers = {
    "Authorization": BEARER,
    "If-None-Match": None,
    "OData-Version": "4.0",
    "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "MSCRM.SuppressDuplicateDetection": "true",
    "If-Match": "*"
}

lead_qualify_url = f"{data_url}leads({lead_guid})/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.QualifyLead"
data = {
    'CreateAccount': False,
    'CreateContact': True,
    'CreateOpportunity':False,
    'Status':3
}
qualify_lead_response = requests.post(lead_qualify_url, headers=api_surpress_dup_detection_headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

The result I get is:

> <Response [412]> '{"error":{"code":"0x80040333","message":"A record
> was not created or updated because a duplicate of the current record
> already exists."}}'

If anyone has solved this before I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/manage-duplicate-detection-create-update), I see that adding `MSCRM.SuppressDuplicateDetection` in request header works for CREATE and UPDATE request.

For `QualifyLead` action - this may be little different. Instead of adding request header - you may need to include in payload like explained in [this blog](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/isaacnichols/2019/07/22/using-the-qualify-lead-action-in-dynamics-365).

```
this.SuppressDuplicateDetection = true  // or false

"SuppressDuplicateDetection": {
     "typeName": "Edm.Boolean", "structuralProperty": 1
 }
```

Comment: You are incredible thank you! This ended up working.

Comment: @GrantCulp happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Arun Vinoth
Here is the final code that I used in case someone else has this question

```
api_surpress_dup_detection_headers = {
    'Authorization': BEARER,
    'OData-Version': '4.0',
    'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'MSCRM.SuppressDuplicateDetection': 'true'
}

lead_qualify_url = f"{data_url}leads({lead_guid})/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.QualifyLead"
data = {
    'CreateAccount': False,
    'CreateContact': True,
    'CreateOpportunity':False,
    'Status':3,
    'SuppressDuplicateDetection': True
}
qualify_lead_response = requests.post(lead_qualify_url, headers=api_surpress_dup_detection_headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

You should get a 200 response and be good to go!

Comment: Do you need it in header too? I guess not

Comment: @ArunVinoth you do not need it in the header just the body. Documentation is a little misleading if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: agreed. I raised a github issue last week, lets see for further updates. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/2166